# Proving a correct system satisfying certain conditions is incomplete

Tags: logic, solution-verification, incompleteness

I was reading R. Smullyan's book, Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems and got stuck at an exercise:

In the following problem $P$ denotes the set of Gödel numbers of provable statements in system $\mathcal{L}$. A set of natural number $A$ is said to be *expressible* in $\mathcal{L}$ if there exists a predicate $H$ such that, $H(n)\ \text{is true}\iff n\in A$. For any natural number $n$, let $E_n$ be the sentence in $\mathcal{L}$ with Gödel  number $n$. Let $d(n)$ be the Gödel  number of the sentence $E_n(n)$. Now for any set $A$ of natural numbers we denote by $A^{\ast}$, the set of natural numbers which satisfies the condition: $n\in A^{\ast}\iff d(n)\in A$. A system $\mathcal{L}$ is said to be *incomplete* if there is a sentence that is neither provable nor refutable in $\mathcal{L}$. A system $\mathcal{L}$ is said to be *correct* if all provable statements are true and all refutable statements are false.

**Problem:** Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is a correct system such that the following two conditions hold:

1. The set $P^{\ast}$ is expressible in $\mathcal{L}$,
2. For any predicate $H$, there is a predicate $H'$, such that for every $n$, the sentence $H'(n)$ is provable in $\mathcal{L}$ if and only if $H(n)$ is refutable in $\mathcal{L}$.

Then $\mathcal{L}$ is incomplete.

**My attempt:** Let $H$ be the predicate that expresses $P^{\ast}$. Let $H'$ be the predicate corresponding to $H$ as guaranteed by condition 2. Let $h$ be the Gödel  number of $H'$. Then
\begin{multline}
H'(h)\ \text{is provable}\iff H(h)\ \text{is refutable}\implies H(h)\ \text{is not true}\\\iff h\not\in P^{\ast}\iff d(h)\not\in P\implies H'(h)\ \text{is not provable}
\end{multline}
Hence I have shown that the sentence $H'(h)$ cannot be provable. Now I need to show that $H'(h)$ is also not refutable. This is where I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

**Addendum:** I have figured out a way to prove the problem. I just want you to *verify the proof*.

Suppose $H'(h)$ is refutable. This would mean $H'(h)$ is not true and hence not provable, which means $H(h)$ is not refutable. If the system $\mathcal{L}$ were indeed complete, then this would mean that $H(h)$ is true (because a false statement which is not refutable makes the system incomplete, as that statement is also not provable under the assumption of correctness).
$$H(h)\ \text{is true}\iff h\in P^{\ast}\iff d(h)\in P$$
Now $d(h)$ is the Gödel number of $H'(h)$, so $d(h)\in P$ means that $H'(h)$ is provable, contradicting our assumption that it is refutable. Hence the system cannot be complete.

Comment: Good Gödel, I think this is it. It has been a long time I have been with this doubt. The last implication in the proof of the non-provability of $H'(h)$ isn't a bi-implication?

Comment: Couldn't you do the same argument in proof of non-refutability you did for the proof of the non-provability? I mean:

\begin{multline}
H'(h)\ \text{is refutable}\iff H(h)\ \text{is provable}\implies H(h)\ \text{is  true}\\\iff h\in P^{\ast}\iff d(h)\in P\iff H'(h)\ \text{is provable}
\end{multline}